# Android ArrayAdapter causes NullPointerException when used in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter

I've serched everywhere but I haven't solved my problem yet.

I'm using a ViewPager inside an Activity. The ViewPager contains 3 fragments: one is a plain fragment, the second Fragment contains a custom ListView and the third is a MapFragment (SupportMapFragment).

I'm using only support fragments.

The problem is that the getItem() method of the ViewPager adapter (FragmentPagerAdapter) is called after the activity tries to populate the fragments setting the adapter and the markers on the map.

So, I'm triyng to initialize the fragment before initializing the ViewPager, using a singleton pattern for the fragments:

In the Activity onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.act_discover_small);
profiloFragment = new ProfiloFragment();
mapFragment = new MappaMonumentiFragment();
elencoFragment = new ElencoMonumentiFragment();
initViewPager();
```

The initViewPager() method is:

```
private void initViewPager() {
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (SmartViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            if (!beginSwipe)
                elencoFragment.List.finishRefresh();
            beginSwipe = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            beginSwipe = false;
            lockDrawer(arg0);
            if (arg0 == 0) {
                swipe_left_button.setText("show map");
            } else {
                swipe_left_button.setText("show list");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the ViewPager adapter

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItem viewpager n." + i);
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            if (profiloFragment == null)
                profiloFragment = new ProfiloFragment();
            return profiloFragment;
        case 1:
            if (elencoFragment == null)
                elencoFragment = new ElencoMonumentiFragment();
            return elencoFragment;
        case 2:
            if (mapFragment == null)
                mapFragment = new MappaMonumentiFragment();
            return mapFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException when triyng to fill the ArrayAdapter of the second fragment with the elements in this method (executed in the onPostExecute() of an AsyncTask):

```
    public void populateElencoMonumenti(List<SmartPlace> placesList) {
    if (placesList != null) {
        places = (ArrayList<SmartPlace>) placesList;
        //before: adapter.clear(); //NullPointerException at this line
                    //after:
                    if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new ElencoMonumentiAdapter(ctx, act, app);
        }


        adapter.addAll(places);
        List.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {
        adapter.clear();
        List.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

If I log (adapter == null) before calling adapter.clear() it return true, so it's null.

if I try to check if it's null and reinitialize it I get a NPE in the constructor of the adapter:

```
   public ElencoMonumentiAdapter(Context ctx, Discover homAct, SmartApplication app) {
    // super(ctx, R.layout.list_row_monument);
    super(ctx, R.layout.list_row_monument, new ArrayList<SmartPlace>()); //NPE here
    Log.e(TAG, "null ctx? " + (ctx == null));
    this.app = app;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

the stacktrace is:

```
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865): Process: com.Thinple.MiWalks.ui, PID: 20865
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.Thinple.MiWalks.ui.adapters.ElencoMonumentiAdapter.<init>(ElencoMonumentiAdapter.java:41)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.Thinple.MiWalks.ui.fragments.ElencoMonumentiFragment.populateElencoMonumenti(ElencoMonumentiFragment.java:129)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.Thinple.MiWalks.ui.Discover.notifyFragments(Discover.java:328)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.Thinple.MiWalks.ui.Discover.populatePlaces(Discover.java:509)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.Thinple.MiWalks.threading.tasks.GetPlacesFromDBtask.onPostExecute(GetPlacesFromDBtask.java:53)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.Thinple.MiWalks.threading.tasks.GetPlacesFromDBtask.onPostExecute(GetPlacesFromDBtask.java:1)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-18 11:13:07.285: E/AndroidRuntime(20865):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really don't find a solution.

Thanks in advance for the replies.

Comment: adapter is null where is it declared and initialized?

Comment: In the Fragment onStart() I do this:

  adapter = new ElencoMonumentiAdapter(ctx, act, app);
  List.setAdapter(adapter);
  Log.e(TAG, "adapter null? " + (adapter == null));

and the log prints false.. so it's not null!

EDIT: I've tried to move that code alson in onAttach() or onCreateView() but it didn't work.

Comment: its is null if not you won't NPE at the line. WHat is ctx by the way

Comment: @Raghunandan I cannot let you see the whole code because it's some thousands line of code, but I promise you that the log are correct, and I've never had a log saying that adapter is null. the NPE is thrown when I try to clear the adapter but loggin before doing that says it's not null. 

I think that there are some issues with the visibility of the fragments or the class loaders

Comment: ok can you post the stacktrace atleast

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I made a mistake, if I log before the adapter.clear() it says that it's null, ok.

I tried to check if it's null and in case reinitialize it but now the NPE is in the super call of the adapter constructor. I edited my question

Comment: where do you pass the array list to the constructor of adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
super(ctx, R.layout.list_row_monument, new ArrayList<SmartPlace>());
```

`new ArrayList<SmartPlace>()` is new arraylsit but its empty not populated with any data

to

```
super(ctx, R.layout.list_row_monument, list);
```

list is probably  `ArrayList<SmartPlace>()` which is passed to the constructor of adapter class

Look at the public constructors

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: This line is correct! the NPE is no more thrown! thank you! I'll accept your answer but the problem is not yet solved because the other fragment, the mapfragment now throw the NPE

Comment: @LorenzoBarbagli that is different question. Ask a new question with the relevant stack trace and relevant piece of code. I am sure that can be solved as well

Comment: Ok it's not necessary, I solved it, just control if the map is null and in case reinitialize it by calling getMap() from the fragment.

Thank you very much for your help. May you tell me why super(ctx, R.layout.list_row_monument, list); is working and the other no? thanks!